# How to play array of words or NSString using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, media-player, avaudioplayer

I have Array of words which i want to pick one after the other and play using AVAudioPlayer, how can i achieve playing NSString using AVAudioPlayer?

I don't have the audio file and i have list of words to which i want to play each word using AVAudioPlayer programming .

i found to play the audio file using AVAudioPlayer but not able to find to play NSSting or word in AVAudioPlayer

Below is the code using to play the audio clips :

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audio.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
```

Comment: Use an `AVSpeechSynthesizer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an [`AVSpeechUtterance`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechutterance?language=objc) object using the words that you want the device to "speak," and then pass that object to [`AVSpeechSynthesizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer?language=objc). Those classes provide the methods you need to control the speech; there's no need to use `AVAudioPlayer`.